# Call a Polars UDF with two pl.Series arguments inline

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I want to call inline a polars udf with two Series arguments.

```
import polars as pl

def prefix_cat_based_on_num_order(cat_col: pl.Series, num_col: pl.Series) -> pl.Series:
    X = pl.DataFrame({"cat_col": cat_col, "num_col": num_col})

    X_agg_order = (
        X
        .groupby("cat_col")
        .agg(avg_num_col=pl.col("num_col").mean()).sort("avg_num_col")
        .with_columns(pl.int_range(0, pl.count()).alias("row_num"))
    )

    res = X.join(X_agg_order, on="cat_col", how="inner").with_columns(
        pl.concat_str(pl.col("row_num"), pl.lit("_"), pl.col("cat_col")).alias("cat_col_w_prefix"))

    return res["cat_col_w_prefix"]

df = (pl.DataFrame({"my_col": range(10000)})
      .with_columns(pl.col("my_col").cast(pl.Float64).round().qcut(q=3).alias("q_my_col")))

df2 = df.with_columns(prefix_cat_based_on_num_order(df["q_my_col"], df["my_col"]).alias("q_my_col_w_prefix"))
```

Being able to do something like that would be great:

```
df = (pl.DataFrame({"my_col": range(10000)})
.with_columns(pl.col("my_col").cast(pl.Float64).round().qcut(q=3).alias("q_my_col"),
'call to prefix_cat_based_on_num_order here'.alias("q_my_col_w_prefix")
))
```

Comment: Sounds like perhaps you're looking for [`.pipe()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pipe.html#polars.DataFrame.pipe)

Comment: My understanding is that .pipe work on dataframe, while I want to call my udf within a with_columns()

Comment: Are you just trying to prefix each value with the "group number" based on the cat column?